.NET web deployment with Terraform doesn't deploy
I am trying to deploy a .NET web application in Azure using Terraform.
This is the link to the public repository in GitHub that contains the .NET web: https://github.com/iboncas/dotnetweb.git.
This is my main.tf file:
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}

variable "github_auth" {
  type        = string
  description = "Token for authorization"
  default = "xxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "web-rg"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "appservice-iboncas"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "westeurope"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "linux-app" {
  name                = "linux-web-iboncas"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "westeurope"
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only = true
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = "8.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "source_control" {
  app_id                 = azurerm_linux_web_app.linux-app.id
  repo_url               = "https://github.com/iboncas/dotnetweb.git"
  branch                 = "main"
  use_manual_integration = true
}

resource "azurerm_source_control_token" "source_token" {
  type         = "GitHub"
  token        = var.github_auth
  token_secret = var.github_auth
}

When the web is deployed, I get a web page saying something along the lines of: The web application is being executed and waiting for content. It can take up to 5 minutes to show the content.
What can I do?

The web application is being executed and waiting for content. It can take up to 5 minutes to show the content. - what happens after 5 or even 10 minutes?

Even after waiting for an hour, nothing still appears

I deployed your web app project using terraform web app Infrastructure  on Linux was deployed properly but getting error in app deployment . Deployment logs can be checked in Deployment Centre > Logs.In logs mentioned error was related to .NET version used.
Command: oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version 8.0 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log  -i /tmp/8dca64c7de98b7c | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20240424.1, Commit: d37b2225a252ab2c04b4726024d047cf01ea1318, ReleaseTagName: 20240424.1

Build Operation ID: 2e0d1883060a902c
Repository Commit : a992c18a9209afdd1380c98d168200758978542e
OS Type           : bookworm
Image Type        : githubactions

Detecting platforms...
Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo.
Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo.\n/bin/bash -c "oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version 8.0 -p virtualenv_name= --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log  -i /tmp/8dca64c7de98b7c | tee /tmp/oryx-build.log ; exit $PIPESTATUS "


Issue is not related to terraform code but it is related to .NET version you are using. .NET 4.8 in not supported on Linux in azure now.
I deployed the same web app on windows web app I am able to view the Default.asax page.
Below given code of terraform  for windows app worked for me.

Note :- azurerm_app_service_source_control_token is deprecated, instead use azurerm_source_control_token

My Directory :-

terraform {
required_providers {
  azurerm ={
    source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    version = "=3.104.0"
  }
}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "serviceplan" {
  name = "ASP-terrafomdotnetplan"
  resource_group_name = "<resourcegroupname>"
  location = "Australia East"
  os_type = "Windows"
  sku_name = "P1v3"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "webapp" {
  name = "dotnetweb17july"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_service_plan.serviceplan.resource_group_name
  location = azurerm_service_plan.serviceplan.location
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.serviceplan.id
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      current_stack = "dotnet"
      dotnet_version = "v8.0"
    }
    
  }
  
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "githuburl" {
  app_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.webapp.id
  repo_url = "https://github.com/Shandilyavivek/iboncas-dotnetweb.git"
  branch = "main"
  use_manual_integration = true
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control_token" "name" {
  type = "Github"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }

OUTPUT:



Yes, using Linux instead of Windows was definitely the problem. Thanks for your help!
